# When to remove event listeners?

Tags: actionscript-3, events

How do you know **when** you should remove event listeners?

For example, I know that if I have a TimerEvent listener, I can safely remove that event when I have stopped and / or deleted my timer.

Or, if I have a display object on the stage, and I remove it, I can safely remove any event listeners associated with the display object.

Any other examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two reasons to remove event listeners:

1. You no longer want to receive events for whatever reason.  This is pretty straight-forward.  Your code is done listening and turns it off.
2. You are done with the object and you want it to be garbage collected.  This is a more subtle one, but if not done properly can lead to real memory leaks.  You see, when an observer adds an event listener to an observable, the observable keeps a reference to the observer.  Because of this, you can release your reference to the observer, think it will get garbage collected, but it won't if the observable is still alive.  Since the observable can't know when to release the listener, you have effectively created a memory leak!  Your code doesn't have an explicit reference to it, so you can't unhook it, and the observable won't do it eiher.  So, if you want an object to be completely de-referenced and therefore properly garbage collected, you need to remove the event listener.